# How does the swimm verify command scope change?

Tags: continuous-integration, code-documentation, swimm

I'm part of the beta using [Swimm](https://swimm.io) for documentation and have created some documents with coupled code snippets. I'm able to verify that the documents have up to date snippets using the `swimm verify` command, as follows:

```
13:00:13:~/Desktop/code/repo % swimm verify
✔ Document 1 (ADXCUIXLrqISQUgIemgc) is verified.
✔ Document 2 (UeEdKW3ITW8vWbwWSxkz) is verified.
✔ Document 3 (YvBJpI9v8MzH9hc9CYR4) is verified.
✔ Document Z (Z7EBZxocB2N3P7Y5LRl9) is verified.
```

However, I'm trying to simulate the [Github Actions hook](https://docs.swimm.live/Workflow/Continuous%20Integration#github-actions) failing (locally) by making minor changes to the code highlighted in snippets, and noticed that not all of those that I changed went out of sync.
Did I just not change enough, or is there something else that causes the verification hook to trip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work for Swimm.

The `swimm verify` command doesn’t look at changes until they’re actually *staged*, so you won’t see their effect until you `git add` them to be committed.

That’s currently the best compromise as far as workflows go, so you do have the opportunity to see if a commit would cause the docs to become outdated (and fix them prior). But, as you note by asking, it can be a little confusing.